# How accurate is the saying that fat loss occurs first in the place it was put on last, and vice versa?

Tags: nutrition, diet, weight

I've heard that you lose fat in the areas it was last gained. Similarly, the last place you'll lose it is the area you first put on the weight. What is the reason behind this mechanism? Is it a myth?